# Union of 2 expander graphs

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, expanders

Suppose that $G$ and $H$ are both expander graphs on the same node set with a second largest eigenvalue of $\lambda_G$ resp. $\lambda_H$.

- What can be said about the expansion of graph $G \cup H$? In particular, is the spectral gap of $G \cup H$ at least as large as the minimum of the spectral gaps of $G$ and $H$?
- Does it make a difference whether $G$ and $H$ both have constant node degree?

This is certainly true for the *edge expansion* of $G \cup H$, since it can only increase by adding edges. 
I know that spectral expansion and edge expansion are related by the [Cheeger inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheeger_constant_%28graph_theory%29#Cheeger_Inequalities), but using this route we only get a bound on the *spectral expansion* of $G \cup H$ that is **worse** than $\lambda_G$ and $\lambda_H$.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this on cstheory.

Comment: Or [mathoverflow.se]? But please don't just post a second copy there: pick one place, click the "flag" link and ask the moderators to migrate your post.

Comment: now on [tcs.se](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21912/)

Comment: Manually migrated to another site, cstheory.se.

Comment: Although the question is on-topic, it has been [reposted on Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21912/expansion-of-the-union-of-two-expander-graphs), so I am closing it here.